# Is there a Groovy equivalent of the Ruby Timeout module?

Tags: ruby, groovy, timeout

In Ruby I would use the Timeout module, where it executes a block and will stop executing the code if it passes the timeout.

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```

Does Groovy have something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `TimedInterrupt` [annotation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TimedInterrupt.html), but I've not tried it out yet...

Gave it a quick test, and this (poor example):

```
@groovy.transform.TimedInterrupt( 5L )
def loopy() {
  int i = 0
  try {
    while( true ) {
      i++
    }
  }
  catch( e ) {
    i
  }
}

println loopy()
```

Runs in the groovy console and prints out `i` after 5 seconds.

I get:

```
47314150
```